# Tkinter checkbox to negate asterisks in entry field

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have an entry field meant for passwords like this:

```
Input = Entry(MainWindow, show="*")
```

It hides whatever you type. I created a checkbox "show password" that when pressed, is supposed to reveal what is in the entry box.

```
CheckBox = Checkbutton(MainWindow, text="Show password", variable=Checked, command=Stars)
```

Where the function Stars is meant to turn on or off the aterisks in the entry field. I'm having trouble writing the function Stars and making it do what I want.

I tried

```
def Stars():
print("check box")

if (Checked.get()):
    Input.config(show=None)
else:
    Input.config(show="*")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not knowing how your widgets are related to each other, I'd go with `Input.config(show=None)`

Comment: I tried def Stars():
    ' print("check box")
    
    if (Checked.get()):
        Input.config(show=None)
    else:
        Input.config(show="*") '

The function runs but nothing happens to the stars

Comment: Try to remove the if-statement altogether.

Comment: I tried 

`def Stars():
    Input.config(show=None)` 

and it still didn't work. The function runs but the input box remains the same

Comment: Sorry, at the moment I can't test the code. The last thing that comes to mind: `Input.config(show='')`

Comment: Hey that worked! Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
def Stars():
    Input.config(show='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Same situation here, this code worked for me:

```py
def stars():
    Input.config(show="")

    if (Checked.get()):
        Input.config(show=None)
    else:
        Input.config(show="*")
```